# how to initiate a specific node as infected in Linear Threshold Model python

Tags: python, python-3.x, threshold, linearmodels

I'm trying to use the Linear Threshold Model in Python.
I have a graph of nodes and I want to define one node that will be the first one infected.
I saw that by using 'fraction_infected' I can choose a fraction of my nodes that will be infected in the first iteration. I'm looking for a different option, where instead of fraction I can define a specific node as the only one infected at the first iteration.

this is my code :

```
# linear threshold model
# Model selection
model = ep.ThresholdModel(G,seed=123)

# Model Configuration
config = mc.Configuration()
config.add_model_parameter('fraction_infected', 0.1)



# Setting node parameters
threshold = 0.12
for i in G.nodes():
    config.add_node_configuration("threshold", i, threshold)

model.set_initial_status(config)

# Simulation execution
iterations = model.iteration_bunch(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import ndlib.models.ModelConfig as mc

**Model Configuration

config = mc.Configuration()

infected_nodes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

config.add_model_initial_configuration("Infected", infected_nodes)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.